# Scala Future and TimeoutException: how to know the root cause?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

Suppose I have the following code:

```
val futureInt1 = getIntAsync1();
val futureInt2 = getIntAsync2();

val futureSum = for {
  int1 <- futureInt1
  int2 <- futureInt2
} yield (int1 + int2) 

val sum = Await.result(futureSum, 60 seconds)
```

Now suppose one of `getIntAsync1` or `getIntAsync2` takes a very long time, and it leads to `Await.result` throwing exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [60 seconds]
```

How am I supposed to know which one of `getIntAsync1` or `getIntAsync2` was still pending and actually lead to the timeout?

Note that here I'm merging 2 futures with zip, and this is a simple example for the question, but in my app I have this kind of code at different level (ie `getIntAsync1` itself can use `Future.zip` or `Future.sequence`, map/flatMap/applicative)

Somehow what I'd like is to be able to log the pending concurrent operation stacktraces when a timeout occur on my main thread, so that I can know where are the bottlenexts on my system.

---

I have an existing legacy API backend which is not fully reactive yet and won't be so soon. I'm trying to increase response times by using concurrency. But since using this kind of code, It's become way more painful to understand why something takes a lot of time in my app. I would appreciate any tip you can provide to help me debugging such issues.

Comment: What is `result`?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be `futureSum`

Comment: What times out is neither int1 nor int2 but the new future created by yield

Comment: I wish I knew the answer :)

Comment: Let's think about it this way. Say we got much more features in the for block. When our Await times out more than one future can be incomplete.
Would you like to get collection of all these futures?
If yes you can have approximation of that by :
List(futureInt1, futureInt2).filter(!_.isCompleted)

Comment: @Lambder this is probably a first step, but what can I do then once I get a list of futures? Can I get some stacks so that I know which future is blocked at which step? And what can I do if `getIntAsync1 ` is already a combination of 2 futures?

Comment: You don't need stacks to know which futures are still pending. I'll answer the question to provide the example code

Comment: @Lambder if I know which future is pending, and this future is already a merge of 2 other futures, how can I know which of the 2 "subfutures" is pending?

Comment: If future F3 is pending and it relies on two ther F1 and F2 futures, then F1 or F2 will be on a pending futures list as well. All you need is to create a list of all features manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is realizing is that a *the Future* doesn't time out in your example—it's your calling thread which pauses for at most X time.

So, if you want to model *time* in your Futures you should use zipWith on each branch and zip with a Future which will contain a value within a certain amount of time. If you use Akka then you can use `akka.pattern.after` for this, together with Future.firstCompletedOf.

Now, even if you do, how do you figure out *why* any of your futures weren't completed in time, perhaps they depended on other futures which didn't complete.

The question boils down to: Are you trying to do some root-cause analysis on throughput? Then you should monitor your ExecutionContext, not your Futures. Futures are only values.

Comment: I would be ok to do a thread dump when contention happen, is there a way to trigger the thread dump at the appropriate time? Like when the EC limit is reached?

Comment: You can most definitely do that if you write a custom EC.

Comment: Hmm never done that before, but will probably try that yes!

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution wraps each future from for block into TimelyFuture which requires timeout and name. Internally it uses Await to detect individual timeouts.
Please bear in mind this style of using futures is not intended for production code as it uses blocking. It is for diagnostics only to find out which futures take time to complete.

```
package xxx

import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

import scala.concurrent.{Future, _}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class TimelyFuture[T](f: Future[T], name: String, duration: Duration) extends Future[T] {

  override def onComplete[U](ff: (Try[T]) => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit = f.onComplete(x => ff(x))

  override def isCompleted: Boolean = f.isCompleted

  override def value: Option[Try[T]] = f.value

  @scala.throws[InterruptedException](classOf[InterruptedException])
  @scala.throws[TimeoutException](classOf[TimeoutException])
  override def ready(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): TimelyFuture.this.type = {
    Try(f.ready(atMost)(permit)) match {
      case Success(v) => this
      case Failure(e) => this
    }
  }

  @scala.throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def result(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): T = {
    f.result(atMost)
  }

  override def transform[S](ff: (Try[T]) => Try[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    val p = Promise[S]()
    Try(Await.result(f, duration)) match {
      case s@Success(_) => ff(s) match {
        case Success(v) => p.success(v)
        case Failure(e) => p.failure(e)
      }
      case Failure(e) => e match {
        case e: TimeoutException => p.failure(new RuntimeException(s"future ${name} has timed out after ${duration}"))
        case _ => p.failure(e)
      }
    }
    p.future
  }

  override def transformWith[S](ff: (Try[T]) => Future[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    val p = Promise[S]()
    Try(Await.result(f, duration)) match {
      case s@Success(_) => ff(s).onComplete({
        case Success(v) => p.success(v)
        case Failure(e) => p.failure(e)
      })
      case Failure(e) => e match {
        case e: TimeoutException => p.failure(new RuntimeException(s"future ${name} has timed out after ${duration}"))
        case _ => p.failure(e)
      }
    }
    p.future
  }
}

object Main {

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f = Future {
      Thread.sleep(5);
      1
    }

    val g = Future {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      2
    }

    val result: Future[(Int, Int)] = for {
      v1 <- new TimelyFuture(f, "f", 10 milliseconds)
      v2 <- new TimelyFuture(g, "g", 10 milliseconds)
    } yield (v1, v2)


    val sum = Await.result(result, 1 seconds) // as expected, this throws exception : "RuntimeException: future g has timed out after 10 milliseconds"
  }
}
```

Comment: that also seems a valid solution for the first level future composition, but will not really handle deeply nested level of future composition imho

Comment: hmmm yes that seems much simpler from an user perspective and could do the job. However, I see some limitations. If I increase the TimelyFuture wait period to like 1 minute, and the global sum awaits only for 1 sec, I'll still have no idea of what's happing, so I'll have to make sure that my parallel computation tree always have lower timeouts for deeper leaves (but that makes sense anyway, just harder to maintain)

Comment: If the global sum awaits for 1 sec it still be blocked for 1 minute as the internal futures will block. Thus my comment not to use it in production.
I understand what you want to achieve but I think it is not possible in the model of composing the futures in for block as it is directly transformed into nested flatMaps. We would have to implement a framework of dependent computations (FRP?)  and keep tracking of the DAG of signals.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to hack something by passing an implicit ComputationContext where AppFutures could register/unregister themselves. Logging that context on timeout could do the job and I could probably be able to get the stacktrace of all the pending computation threads.

Comment: @SebastienLorber You won't get stack traces on incomplete futures as their underlying promises haven't been realized yet. There are simply no threads waiting/blocked. Try to see an incomplete feature as a function reference which was not called yet.
My approach would be to build DAG of computations and to introspect it after some global timeout. The introspection would show which futures which no incomplete dependencies are still incomplete themselves, which would answer your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130025/discussion-between-lambder-and-sebastien-lorber).

Comment: Lambder I'm not using any async tech at the edges of my system (like a async DB driver) so everytime I have a computation it's likely threads are blocked on some internal app computation (like a thread waiting synchronously for DB to answer, because my driver is not async), so if I add/remove threads to a context around every future computation, I can probably get a list of threads that are currently blocked somewhere.

Comment: @SebastienLorber In that case I'd not bother with futures at all but as you mentioned I'd look at threads in the execution context. You'd see which threads are blocked.

Comment: If I have blocking drivers it's still a good idea to process in parallel to increase response time. I'll try this approach and see where it goes

Comment: @SebastienLorber sure, I don't mind using futures. What I mean is not to introspect them. Check blocked threads instead.

Comment: Sorry for being negative, but sadly the proposed code violates the Future contracts in the most questionable of ways. Apologies for the criticism. √

Comment: @ViktorKlang Please do not apologies. You are absolutely right. I provided the code not as a ultimate solution but rather as an illustration that in order to find incomplete futures we need to block on them which is wrong.

Comment: @SebastienLorber it would be worth looking at scalaz Future (https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.1/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Future.scala)

Answer (score 1):

If you are merely looking for informational metrics on which individual future was taking a long time  (or in combination with others), your best bet is to use a wrapper when creating the futures to log the metrics:

```
    object InstrumentedFuture {
        def now() = System.currentTimeMillis()
        def apply[T](name: String)(code: => T): Future[T] = {
           val start = now()
           val f = Future { 
            code 
           }
           f.onComplete {
              case _ => println(s"Future ${name} took ${now() - start} ms") 
           }
           f
        }
    }


    val future1 = InstrumentedFuture("Calculator") { /*...code...*/ }
    val future2 = InstrumentedFuture("Differentiator") { /*...code...*/ }
```

Comment: That seems like a decent and simple idea :) will probably not solve fully my problem but can help debugging most simple cases

Comment: the proposed solution has a couple of bugs.
Do this instead: `Future({ val s = System.nanoTime(); (Try(code), System.nanoTime() - s) }) transform { case Success((r, t)) => { println(s"Future ${name} took $t ns"); r } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a future has completed by calling its isComplete method

```
if (futureInt1.isComplete) { /*futureInt2 must be the culprit */ } 
if (futureInt2.isComplete) { /*futureInt1 must be the culprit */ }
```

Comment: except by the time we execute these two lines both futures can be completed as the code and prior Await ops are not atomic

Comment: True.  Another option would be to await the result of each individual future:  val futureInt1 = Future { Await.result(getIntAsync1(), 60 seconds) }  and use the for comprehension over those futures instead.

Comment: That would change the semantics slightly as we no longer await for 60 in total.

Comment: No, the semantics that he wants is to know which future failed to complete in 60 seconds.  In order to do that, he would need to await each individually.  He can also still Await the result of the for comprehension as well.

Comment: Hmmm that could do the job @JonAnderson but the problem is that my real code is more complicated and it's not just future1.zip(future2) but rather future1 is already using Future.sequence etc

Comment: @SebastienLorber will it be satisfactory if you had one timeout value for each future separately? If yes, one solution would be to create a future wrapper which would transform each future into one wrapping in Try similar to one proposed by EmiCareOfCell44 but which would actually work

Answer (score 0):

As a first approach i would suggest to lift your Future[Int] into Future[Try[Int]]. Something like that:

```
object impl {

  def checkException[T](in: Future[T]): Future[Try[T]] = 
    in.map(Success(_)).recover {
      case e: Throwable => {   
        Failure(new Exception("Error in future: " + in))
      }
    }

  implicit class FutureCheck(s: Future[Int]) {
   def check = checkException(s)
  }
}
```

Then a small function to combine the results, something like that:

```
object test {

  import impl._

  val futureInt1 = Future{ 1 }
  val futureInt2 = Future{ 2 }

  def combine(a: Try[Int], b: Try[Int])(f: (Int, Int) => (Int)) : Try[Int] = {
    if(a.isSuccess && b.isSuccess) {
      Success(f(a.get, b.get))
    }
   else 
     Failure(new Exception("Error adding results"))
  }

  val futureSum = for {
    int1 <- futureInt1.check
    int2 <- futureInt2.check
  } yield combine(int1, int2)(_ + _)
}
```

In futureSum you will have a Try[Int] with the integer or a Failure with the exception corresponding with the possible error.

Maybe this can be useful

Comment: This example is a nice illustration of future failure handling. But I don't think a timeout is a future failure, so it is not answering the original question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
val futureInt1 = getIntAsync1();
val futureInt2 = getIntAsync2();

val futureSum = for {
  int1 <- futureInt1
  int2 <- futureInt2
} yield (int1 + int2) 

Try(Await.result(futureSum, 60 seconds)) match {
   case Success(sum) => println(sum)
   case Failure(e)   => println("we got timeout. the unfinished futures are: " + List(futureInt1, futureInt2).filter(!_.isCompleted)
}
```

Comment: What if futureInt1 is already a composition of other futures? I want to know which possibly deeply nested future is taking long time, not just at the most high-level future composition